# Case in where clause with null value

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause

I want to check if the value is exist in the column than give that record, else give record which have NULL value in it.

Here is the sample query but it is not working for me as syntax is not correct.

```
SELECT *
FROM t_config_rule
WHERE rule = (
  CASE
    WHEN rule = 'IND'
    THEN 'IND'
    ELSE NULL
  END)
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result; as is, it's not clear to me what you want to achieve. Also, what does "not working" mean? Are you having an error? Which one?The syntax looks correct to me...

Comment: use is NULL to get data

Answer (score 2):

A `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` clause makes no sense, as you can always say the same with simple `AND` and/or `OR`. Your condition translates to:

```
WHERE rule = 'IND' OR rule = NULL
```

As `rule = NULL` is never true (it would have to be `rule IS NULL` for this to work), the condition is essentially a mere

```
WHERE rule = 'IND'
```

You seem to want something entirely different anyway, it seems. You seem to want to look for one single record. It shall be the one with `rule = 'IND'`. If that record does no exist, you want the record with `rule IS NULL` instead.

So select both records, the one with `'IND'` and the one with `NULL`, and then keep the preferred one:

```
SELECT *
FROM t_config_rule
WHERE rule = 'IND' OR rule IS NULL
ORDER BY rule NULLS LAST
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

The FETCH FIRST clause is available only as of Oracle 12c, though. For older versions use:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT *
  FROM t_config_rule
  WHERE rule = 'IND' OR rule IS NULL
  ORDER BY rule NULLS LAST
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

or number the rows with `ROW_NUMBER` and keep the first row:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT r. *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rule NULLS LAST) AS rn
  FROM t_config_rule r
  WHERE rule = 'IND' OR rule IS NULL
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

`FETCH FIRST` and `ROW_NUMBER` are standard SQL, whereas `ROWNUM` is Oracle-only (and even violating the standard at that).